# how can i implement date conversions in typo3 repository methods

Tags: mysql, typo3, extbase

I have a query

```
SELECT * FROM `my_table` 
WHERE DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), CAST(from_unixtime(tstamp) AS DATE)) >=365
```

How can I convert to repository method

```
$query = $this->createQuery();
$query->statement();
$query->matching(
        $query->greaterThanOrEqual(????, 365)
    );
return $query->execute();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just calculate that date with PHP:

```
$timestamp = time() - 86400 * 365;
$query->matching(
    $query->lessThanOrEqual('tstamp', $timestamp )
);
```

Comment: Dimitri L. Its working perfectly.Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

This is not directly possible in extbase. However I see 2 possible options

**Variant 1**

Use the native SQL query to return the uids of the records and use those in the extbase query:

```
 $query->in('uid', $idList)
```

**Variant 2**

It is possible to manipulate the query, however this is quite an overhead. You can take a look at https://github.com/TYPO3-extensions/news/blob/master/Classes/Domain/Repository/AbstractDemandedRepository.php#L90 to get an idea.

Comment: Your answer is right.But I got more clear anwer from another.